# Why does the 7th amendment not apply in traffic cases?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, seventh-amendment

In my city (Lansing, Michigan), and apparently in many other cities, you are not allowed trial by jury for traffic violations.  This seems to be in direct contradiction to the 7th amendment.  Is there a reason for this?  Is it unconstitutional?

Comment: Can you provide a link showing such a restriction? http://courts.mi.gov/self-help/center/casetype/pages/misdemeanor.aspx says you may have a trial before a judge or jury.

Comment: @user6726 The same website applies http://courts.mi.gov/self-help/center/casetype/pages/infraction.aspx

Comment: I don't see any mention of juries on that page.

Comment: @user6726 http://cityofeastlansing.com/807/Ticket-Options

Comment: I don't see any mention of juries on that page either. Has some person in authority actually told you that a jury trial is impossible?

Comment: @user6726 Not explicitly, but looking at the options here it seems so, correct?  It says you can request a formal hearing before a judge, but there is no mention of a jury.

Comment: Maybe: but again maybe thet don't want to advertise that available option. Courts never advertise the fact that you can appeal a decision up to the Supreme Court.

Answer (score 7):

The Seventh Amendment's jury trial provision does not apply to the states. The Bill of Rights does not inherently restrain the states at all, merely the federal government. The Fourteenth Amendment *does* restrain the states; notably, it forbids a state from depriving any person of life, liberty, or property without due process of law. Courts have read into "of law" the added requirement that the law be compatible with the fundamental rights that are implicit in the concept of ordered liberty; this means that *most* stuff that would violate the Bill of Rights if done by the feds violates due process if done by the states. However, not all provisions of the Bill of Rights have been incorporated (i.e. applied to the states); the requirement for a jury in a civil trial is one of the few that hasn't been incorporated, because courts do not consider it a fundamental right (merely one protected in the federal courts).

Now, many traffic tickets are actually misdemeanor offenses, and a jury-trial requirement for crimes *is* incorporated. However, even for federal offenses, the courts have generally found that the Constitution doesn't require jury trial for petty crimes (those with a maximum sentence under 6 months).

Comment: You also have the [Privileges or Immunities clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileges_or_Immunities_Clause) to contend with, which is *nearly* a dead letter except that [Justice Thomas recently revived it](http://www.scotusblog.com/2010/06/privileges-or-immunities-clause-alive-again/).

Comment: The Bill of Rights applies to all people in all states. No state has power to deny the rights of the people. The courts are also wrong in their determination to waive defendant rights.

Answer (score 3):

This is the text of the Seventh Amendment:

> In **Suits at common law**, where the value in controversy shall exceed twenty dollars, the right of trial by jury shall be preserved, and no fact tried by a jury, shall be otherwise re-examined in any Court of the United States, than according to the rules of the common law.

"Suits at common law" means (for our purposes) "lawsuits."  In other words, the Seventh Amendment applies to *civil* cases.  Traffic tickets are criminal cases, so the Seventh Amendment does not apply to them at all.

Comment: This is a civil case in my understanding.  That's why it's called a "civil infraction". http://courts.mi.gov/self-help/center/casetype/pages/infraction.aspx

Comment: @MarsOneRover: You'll notice that that website has a separate page for civil lawsuits.  A case is criminal if the government is the plaintiff.  They use the term "civil infraction" to mean that jailtime is not a possible outcome; traffic tickets are still criminal matters, technically speaking.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia [suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) that "twenty dollars" is not interpreted literally, and that the lower limit today is (in some situations) more like $75,000.  So unless you have a really serious traffic ticket...

Comment: @NateEldredge The $75,000 threshold is a limit for diversity cases in federal court, not for a jury trial in case cases. You have a right to a jury trial in all civil cases at law in federal court as the courts choose not to invoke the $20 threshold for administrative reasons. Today $20 as of 1791 when the 7th Amendment was enacted is worth about $500-$1000. But, there is no occasion to test if there can be an inflation adjustment as the courts have not utilized the option to limit jury trials in that manner.

Comment: Some states, like Texas do consider traffic incidents to be criminal cases. In Texas you would have a right to a jury trial. And the 7th amendment has in general been interpreted to be 'incorporated onto the states'

Comment: @ohwilleke: Yes, the $75k is about whether you have the right to be in Federal court at all, not whether you get a jury once you're there.  Once you manage to get into Federal court, you're basically guaranteed a jury trial if you want one.

Comment: @Kevin There is no dollar threshold, however, in federal question cases. You a bring a lawsuit for a violation of a federal law or in a suit involving a federal party (e.g. an unpaid U.S. Department of Education student loan balance) for $12 if you want.

Comment: Specifically $20 in 1791 is worth $482.59 as of 2015. http://www.in2013dollars.com/1791-dollars-in-2015

Comment: @ohwilleke I think $500-$1000 is a far more accurate summary of the current value of tweny 1791 dollars than $482.59.  Getting an accurate measure of comparative value across more than two centuries is conceptually very difficult.  (Are you comparing based on price of a two bedroom house, rent of a two bedroom house, median wages, price of gold, price of a computer, or price of a slave?)

Comment: Then it follows that all defendants in traffic court are entitled to a jury trial. Not just "entitled to"--the Constitution mandates it.